# Form with multiple answers as radio buttons in mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a litle problem with mvc application. I have form, where are many questions and user have to choose one option for every answer. But when I send data to controller, data are null. Can you please help me find solution?

I have one view with form and for every question is partialview, where are stored also answers as radio buttons

**main view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmTestForm", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <progress id="oca-progress" class="oca-progress" max="190" value="0"></progress>
        </div>
    </div>

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Questions.Count; i = i + 10)
    {
        <div id="@($"section-{(i/10)}")" class="@(first ? "" : "oca-hidden")">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>
                        Otázka
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-end">
                    <ul class="oca-test-choices">
                        <li>
                            <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                                <span>A</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                                <span>M</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                                <span>N</span>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="oca-hr" />

            @*@for (int j = i; j < i + 10; j++)*@
            @foreach (var question in Model.Questions.Skip(i).Take(10))
            {
                @Html.Partial("_QuestionDetail", question)

                
            }

            <div id="error-message" class="w-100 invisible oca-validation-error">
                <span>Je potřeba vyplnit všechny odpovědi</span>
            </div>

            @if (i != Model.Questions.Count - 10)
            {
                <div class="row oca-row-button">
                    <div class="col-6 text-start">
                        @if (!first)
                        {
                            <input name="previous" class="oca-test-button" type="button" value="Předchozí" />
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                        <input name="next" class="oca-test-button" type="button" value="Další" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            else
            {
                <div class="row oca-row-button">
                    <div class="col-6 text-start">
                        <input name="previous" class="oca-test-button" type="button" value="Předchozí" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6 text-end">
                        <input class="oca-test-button" type="submit" value="Další" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }

            @if (first)
            {
                first = false;
            }

        </div>
    }
}
```

**partialView with one question**

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label>@($"{Model.Order} - {Model.Name}")</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-end">
            <ul class="oca-test-choices">
                <li>
                    <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Value, ChoiceTypes.Yes, new { @class = "oca-choice" })
                        @*@Html.RadioButton(Model.Order.ToString(), Model.ChoiceYes, new { @class = "oca-choice" })*@
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Value, ChoiceTypes.Maybe, new { @class = "oca-choice" })
                        @*@Html.RadioButton(Model.Order.ToString(), Model.ChoiceMaybe, new { @class = "oca-choice" })*@
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="oca-choice-wrapper">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Value, ChoiceTypes.No, new { @class = "oca-choice" })
                        @*@Html.RadioButton(Model.Order.ToString(), Model.ChoiceNo, new { @class = "oca-choice" })*@
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
  public class QuestionsViewModel
  {
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
  }

  public class QuestionViewModel
  {
    public int Order { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ChoiceTypes? Value { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use checkbox in place of radiobutton for selecting multiple answers.**
[click here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox)